# context tex poster template

Tags: context

There are Latex poster package, such as [beamerposter](http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/latexbeamerposter.php), [baposter](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/), [a0poster](http://andreas.welcomes-you.com/projects/a0poster/) .

Any such resource for making a conference poster in ConTeXt TeX?

Comment: i seldom hear anything about what context is doing, but looking with the help of google, i arrived at [a context wiki entry on presentations](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Presentations).  (there’s a simple package on ctan, but i doubt it’s what you want.)

Comment: The way I see it, creating a poster is as simple as setting the paper size and font size, and then typesetting the content in columns. Another option is to use layers for absolute positioning of content. Is there any particular feature of the LaTeX packages that you cannot translate to ConTeXt?

Answer (score 7):

See also Aditya's blog post [Making visaully attractive posters in ConTeXt](https://adityam.github.io/context-blog/post/poster-in-context/).  While it does not provide you with a ready-made example, it gives a very good conceptual overview.

---

I have come up with a (quite) minimal example for a poster.  As Aditya commented it mainly boils down to setting the paper size and the font size and the typesetting stuff in columns.

CAVEAT: I'm using `columnset` which seems to have some difficulties with MkIV.  For instance `\placefigure` does not seem to play nicely with it.  If you run into problems, ask on the mailing list.  Hans is very responsive and his usual answer is »Fixed in next beta«.

```
\environment poster-environment

\setupbodyfont[sansserif]

\starttext

\setvariables
  [metadata]
  [
    title={My really long and super awesome research title that spans
      multiple lines},
    author={Good guys},
    institute={Institute of the Holy Cow, Ridderstraat 27, 8061GH
      Hasselt, The Netherlands},
    logo={\externalfigure[cow][width=10cm]},
  ]

\startcolumnset[threecolumn]

  \startblock[title=Introduction]
    \input lorem
  \stopblock

  \startblock[title=Knuth]
    \input knuth
  \stopblock

  \startblock[title=Ward]
    \input ward
  \stopblock

\column

  \startblock[title=Zapf]
    \input zapf
  \stopblock

  \externalfigure[cow][width=\textwidth]

  \startblock[title=Hawking]
    \input hawking
  \stopblock

\column

  \startblock[title=Douglas]
    \input Douglas
  \stopblock

  \startblock[title=Bryson]
    \input bryson
  \stopblock

  \externalfigure[cow][width=\textwidth]

\stopcolumnset

\stoptext
```

Because it is good practice to keep style and content separated, I have factored out all the layout into `poster-environment.tex`.  Of course, it does not look so pretty right now, but adding eye-candy is easy.  See [Aditya's impressive git tutorial](https://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/creating-a-clean-presentation-style-in-40-commits/) for details.

```
\startenvironment *

\setuppapersize[A0][A0]

\setupbodyfont[25pt]

\setuplayout
  [
    cutspace=5cm,
    leftmargin=4cm,
    leftmargindistance=1cm,
    width=middle,
    rightmargindistance=1cm,
    rightmargin=4cm,
    backspace=5cm,
    %
    topspace=4cm,
    header=10cm,
    headerdistance=5cm,
    height=middle,
    footerdistance=0pt,
    footer=0pt,
    bottomspace=5cm,
  ]

\setupbackgrounds
  [page]
  [background=color,backgroundcolor=gray]

\definecolumnset
  [threecolumn]
  [n=3]

\setupcolumnset
  [threecolumn][each]
  [
    distance=3cm,
    background=color,
    backgroundcolor=white,
    backgroundoffset=1cm,
    frame=on,
    frameoffset=1cm,
    rulethickness=1pt,
  ]
\setupcolumnset[threecolumn][1][distance=0pt]

\definestyle
  [titlestyle]
  [style={\tfd\setupinterlinespace\WORD}]
\definestyle
  [authorstyle]
  [style={\tfc\setupinterlinespace}]
\definestyle
  [institutestyle]
  [style={\tfb\setupinterlinespace}]

\startsetups header:title
  \framed
    [
      frame=off,
      height=\headerheight,
      width=\dimexpr\makeupwidth-10cm\relax,
      align=middle,
    ]{%
      \titlestyle{\getvariable{metadata}{title}\par}

      \vfill

      \authorstyle{\getvariable{metadata}{author}\par}

      \vfill

      \institutestyle{\getvariable{metadata}{institute}\par}
    }
\stopsetups

\startsetups header:logo
  \framed
    [
      frame=off,
      height=\headerheight,
      width=10cm,
      align=middle,
    ]{%
      \getvariable{metadata}{logo}
    }
\stopsetups

\setupheadertexts[\setups{header:logo}][\setups{header:title}]
\setuppagenumbering[location=]

\definehead
  [block]
  [subject]  
  [
    style=\bfa,
    align=middle,
    before={\blank[line]},
    after={\blank[line]},
    textcommand={\framed[width=.9\textwidth]},
  ]

\stopenvironment
```

[image]